# Mirror Android Secondary Display (Presentation API)

Tags: android, adb, surfaceview, android-displaymanager

I develop an application that presents content to an external display using [Presentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation).
Now I want to mirror that to the phone screen or let say Twilio.
One solution is to capture views from within the app.

For example. Is there a way to set a listener on `DisplayManager` external displays and start recording when it's presenting?
Like we do with ADB
`adb shell screenrecord --display-id [DisplayID] /sdcard/example.mp4`

Can we trigger this programmatically and catch each frame?

Note: We use TextureView

Comment: [This](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts#usage-mirroing) is rather old, but it may give you some ideas.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for sharing this. I look into `MirroringFrameLayout` You wrote very good logic. We are using `TextureView` so I can't use that as it is. Just got an idea. I think I can get a bitmap from `TextureView.getBitmap` and draw on the top with every draw call.

Comment: @CommonsWare mTextureView.isAvailable() returned false from inside MirroringFrameLayout

Comment: @CommonsWare I put the TextureView out of MirroringFrameLayout and now passing to mirroringFrameLayout.setTextureView(textureView), then textureView.getBitmap(bmp); before super.draw(bmpBackedCanvas); working like a charm! thanks